# Is there a way to convert text stored in a textview text storage as HTML characters?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

For example, I have a mini RTF editor that consist of a textview and I change the sizes of text in the text storage. Is there a way I can get these values as HTML? Or would I have to parse it manually?

Answer (score 0):

There is no one to one conversion from the RTF spec to the HTML spec. You will either need to parse/convert yourself, or use a third party HTML - RTF converter.

Since your ultimate goal is to convert the RTF content to PDF, you might like to consider an RTF to PDF Converter.

Comment: i know i am exporting the file as a pdf, but i want to get the text from the text view to store in the pdf exactly the way it looks. So if i can draw the text from the text view that would be nice but the way i see it converting it to html seems easier